# Selenium alert.sendKeys with Chrome is not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, alert, webdriverwait

Here is the code snippet I have:

```
Alert promptAlert  = driver.switchTo().alert();
Thread.sleep(4000);
promptAlert.sendKeys("Accepting the alert");
```

It works perfectly fine in Firefox, but in Chrome does not work. I am using Gecko driver version 0.23.0, Chrome driver version 2.43.0.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

After having had this same exact issue I came to the conclusion that this is purely display issue. The input of sendKeys(...) will be sent after you accept the Alert.

See also the answer in this Chromium issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1120#c11

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because alert blocks the event loop.
You should be ably to disable alerts:

```
driver.executeScript("window.alert = () => 0")
```

Comment: I tried the above, but I am getting an exception saying org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : Please enter your name:}

Comment: Try switching to alert first before executing above code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the **alertIsPresent** as follows:

```
Alert promptAlert  = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
promptAlert.sendKeys("Accepting the alert");
```

Comment: I tried the above, but it did not make any difference. Same results with or without.

Comment: @s7_user Your comment doesn't helps me either. Sorry, the answer didn't help you to solve your problem but how am I going to improve my post with that feedback?

Comment: Not sure what else to add. Added the above code snippet, nothing changed. It executes the sendkey command as it did before adding it, but it does not send any text to the input box of the alert. There are no exceptions thrown that I can add to my comment. What else will help you improve your response. I would be happy to add it if you guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
System.out.println(alert.getText());
alert.sendKeys("testing");
alert.accept();
Thread.sleep(2000);
System.out.println(alert.getText());
```

If it still not work then downgrade the chrome driver version. I hope that'll work.

Answer (score 0):

```
The input value is successful, but the input value is not displayed(By https://translate.google.cn/)

function disp_prompt()
{
  var name=prompt("prompt","~~~")
  if (name!=null && name!="")
  {
    document.write("~~~")
  }
  else
  {
    alert("IS NULL") ;
  }
}
<input id="prompt" type="button" style="width: 200px;height:60px;" onclick="disp_prompt()" value="prompt" />

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(r"C:\Users\1.html")
driver.find_element_by_id("prompt").click()
a = driver.switch_to.alert
a.send_keys("")
a.accept()
```

Comment: Try it and see the result

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was adding two waits, one before and one after sending keys and accepting

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
driver.SwitchTo().Alert().SendKeys("Test");
driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
```